# A tool to troubleshoot DNS issues on Windows that isn't nslookup

Tags: windows, dns

I'm looking for something like `dig` on windows but without installing cygwin or other compatibility layers. http://www.digwebinterface.com is nice but only works for public zones. Sometimes troubleshooting internal resolution by using things like `dig`'s `+trace` option is nice.

I don't have a preference for command-line or GUI-based tools. `nslookup` can do a lot of things, but can be lacking.

Answer (score 1):

For a command line tool, grab the latest BIND distribution from [ISC](http://www.isc.org/downloads/), it includes a pre-compiled dig.exe that works fine from the Windows command line.